# grep with regex syntax on tsv file

Tags: regex, unix, logging, grep, csv

I have a log file and I want to see if it has a log for a particular server with a particular type of access

the line i'm looking for contains something like this

```
my-server-name  12.345.67.890   Type0   Stuff   server-access
```

i care about the line having my-server-name and server-access and want to match everything in between on that line

I am trying this grep and it is not working, but i think the regex is fine

```
grep -P 'my-server-name.*?server-access' myfile.tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=my-server-name).*(?=server-access)' file
  12.345.67.890   Type0   Stuff
```

Comment: when i run that i get the grep usage stuff
i think because of the P flag

Comment: also i tested the regular expression itself and it no longer matches the line

Comment: It works fine to me. What is your OS and grep version?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this,

```
$ grep -oP 'my-server-name\K.*(?=server-access)' file
  12.345.67.890   Type0   Stuff
```